# How to get rid of UDP checksum error messages in virtual console?

Tags: udp, checksum, stdout

Whenever I am streaming a video in the web browser, while connected to my school LAN via ethernet, and switch to the virtual console (ctrl-alt-f1) on Ubuntu, I get an error that looks like the following in my stdout in intervals:

> > [273375.926571] jme 0000:14:00.5: eth0: UDP Checksum error

Since the video is streaming okay, I assume it's a non-critical error, how do I prevent it from being output on the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable RX checksums (replace `eth0` with your interface name).

```
ethtool --offload eth0 rx off
```